# How to create an isolated DOM Element? One that doesn't inherit css from parents etc

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, widget

I am providing a widget to my users. They include my JS api in a script tag. Once they have a `<div class="PutWidgetHere" />` in their body tag, I aim to render an image and a text box inside the div.

My JS api finds the `div` with `class=PutWidgetHere`. It appends an image element and then an `input type=text` element. The input must be placed right at the center of the image so I use absolute positioning relative to the div, z-index and a couple other css properties.

All in all, I am able to accomplish this fine on a blank page. However, if I integrate my widget on a populated page, say the homepage of StackOverflow, things get ugly. It still works but looks ugly. Mostly because my input text inherits CSS properties from the page such as padding, margin, hover etc.

How can I prevent the page from messing with my widget?

Upon research, I found out that you can't disable inheriting of CSS properties for an element. For padding and margin, I could overwrite them using !important but I cannot do this for all possible CSS properties my input could inherit?

I thought of placing an iframe inside the div. But then this makes it impossible for my image and input elements to talk with the host page. Plus, an iframe (borderless) that hosts an image and a button might mess with the parent page?

Any suggestions on how to isolate my input text from parent CSS is welcome :)

Comment: Is there no solutions here? My questions deserves more attention! :) Looking for help...

Answer (score 2):

Get all styles that makes everything ugly and insert them into `style` property of element, with has highest priority then id and class styles.

**Update:**
You can also add some unique ID to your element and create custom stylesheet. You can either add `<style>` with html, or load `<style>` with javascript, or add  to  tag later after page load.

**Update 2**
Here is example of styles override http://jsfiddle.net/zhhxC/

Comment: But it could be included on any page? Then, I would have to insert all possible style properties?

Comment: Not all, only those that can affect on your element. It can be display, background, padding, margin, z-index, font, position, border, outlines...

Comment: Remember this is a widget. It can be included on any page and therefore could be affected possibly by all sorts of styles. My element already has a unique id but I'm not sure I understand what you mean with your update?

Comment: If `id` of your element is really unique, then styles that you add to document shouldn't affect on any other page element. So you just need to create stylesheet with styles that has maximum possible css styles which could affect your element.

Comment: Gusarov I appreciate your answer. To clarify things, can you help me with this example? MY JS api inserts an input `<input id="uniqueInputId />" style="padding-left:3px;"` to the host page. Let's assume the host page already has `input { border: 1px solid; margin-top: 5px; }` in its style. This messes with my input. So to overcome this, you're suggesting that my JS api also appends a `style` element to the document with `#uniqueInputId { border...;margin-top;... }`? It solves the problem for this host page but I'm saying that we don't know where my JS api can be included. It could be any page.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're suggesting to enumerate and override all possible style properties an `input` can take inside `#uniqueInputId { ... }`?